# How do a sum a value to every element in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list:

```
list = [10, 15,14,20]
```

And I would like to sum a variable(lets say add=5) to all elements in that list, to have something like:

```
newlist = [15,20,19,25]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `df['c1'] = df['c1'] + 5`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i got everything wrong, it wanst a df its a list.

Comment: Ok, If that is the case, A simple list comprehension will do the trick. `[i+5 for i in list]`. Note: Always avoid defining variable names with same name as built-in functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List comprehension:

```
l = [10, 15, 14, 20]
nl = [i + 5 for i in l]
```

Map function:

```
l = [10, 15, 14, 20]
nl = list(map(lambda i: i+5, l))
print(nl)
[15, 20, 19, 25]
```

**Don't use `list` keyword**

```
>>> list = [10, 15, 14, 20]
>>> list((3, 5, 7))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-644-e66a8dedf706> in <module>
----> 1 list((3, 5, 7))

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

You override the function `list` by a list:

```
>>> type(list)
type

>>> list = [10, 15, 14, 20]

>>> type(list)
list
```

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension is probably the most pythonic way of doing this.

Like in Corralien's answer (which is very good by the way).

```
l = [10, 15,14,20]

l = [value+5 for value in l]
```

This will result in:

`l = [15, 20, 19, 25]`

In case you don't know how list comprehension works exactly you can break it down into tokens.

The first part `value+5` is essentially what is in the for loop and it is what's being appended to the list, and `for value in l` is just a for loop and goes through each element in list and assigns it to the the variable `value`

Answer (score 0):

You can use you any type of loop for this.

For example with list comprehension:

```
list = [10, 15,14,20]
x = 5
new_list = [i+x for i in list]
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you shadowed the `list` function by using it as a variable.
You can use a loop.

```
list1= [10, 15,14,20]
num1=5
new_l=[num+num1 for num in list1]
print(new_l)
```

Answer (score 0):

if in case you are looking for pandas solution, as you have pandas tag in your question. below solution will help you.

```
import pandas as pd

alist = [10, 15,14,20]  # initial list
const = 5  # constant you want to add

df= pd.DataFrame(data={"A":alist})  # create a dataframe
df["A"] += const  # add constant to dataframe
print(df)  # print dataframe
```

Output:

```
A
0  15
1  20
2  19
3  25
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, that really would be my next question.